# code coloring using xcode plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins, colors

I'm writing a xcode plugin. 
One function of the plugin is to change the color of the code. The coloring is not based on syntax.

eg.

- (id)init {
  }

i'm going to set '-(id)' to yellow and 'i' to blue and 'nit' to black (just an example).

i tried to listen NSTextViewDidChangeTypingAttributesNotification. And in the notification method, i called [textView setTypingAttributes:textAttributes];
but it will cause infinite loop of NSTextViewDidChangeTypingAttributesNotification.

So how can i achieve that? 
Thanks

Comment: can you tell me steps or doc to write Xcode plugin?